# turn list of python arrays into an array of python lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of python arrays like the following:

```
[array([[0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0., 0.]])]
```

My goal is to change them to an array of lists like the following:

```
array([[ 0, 0, 0],
       [ 0, 0, 0],
       [ 0, 0, 0]])
```

I tried the following however I'm getting I'm an error:

```
np.array([my_array[i].tolist() for i in my_array])
```

The following is the error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Could anyone help me understand what's going and what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just concatenate row-wise with [`vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) since they are of shape `(1, 3)` in your example to get the result of shape `(n, 3)`.

```
np.vstack(my_array)
```

Why your current code fails is because you are iterating over every sub-array in `my_array` and trying to index `my_array` with that. So you are indexing a list with `array([[0., 0., 0.]])` which is not a [*scaler*](https://www.mathwords.com/s/scalar.htm) index because it is an *array*.

---

Alternative options:

```
np.array(my_array).reshape(-1, 3)
np.array([e.reshape(-1) for e in my_array])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`np.array([i[0] for i in my_array])`

Since in your case, i is not the index of a, it represents each element in `my_array`

And each of your element in `my_array` is a nested list, you may want to flat the nested list when doing the conversion